# how to run objective-c in windows 7

Tags: objective-c

I want to learn ios development . I have read a few blogs and the first step seems to be learning Objective-C. Since I don't have a Mac, I want to find out if there is any way I can run objective-C on Windows& pc?

Comment: Honestly I wouldn't recommend it. Try get hold of a mac or at the least a linux operating system (all because I here it works better on linux then Windows) but if you insist on doing it on windows then `StilesCrisis`s answer to use http://www.gnustep.org/ would be my recommendation as well.

Comment: You can read this:
http://sweettutos.com/2012/08/11/objective-c-on-windows-yes-you-can/

Answer (score 2):

You can learn Objective C with GNUstep: http://www.gnustep.org/

This will teach you an equivalent to OS X, which is similar to iOS (but definitely not identical). It is also missing a lot of newer/more advanced tech.

Comment: Is this a IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans? Do you just down load it onto your computer and run and compile objective C programs.